# Wordpress Site corrupt - No access to Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress, web, cpanel

I have recently uploaded a new theme to my Wordpress site. Once the theme was activated, all my pages went "completely white", and I am no longer able to access the Wordpress admin / dashboard.

I have tried logging in to the cPanel to remove the theme, however the theme does not appear in the list of files.  I did also select "show hidden files" , and the theme does not appear.

Is there perhaps a way to repair the Wordpress installation without losing the posts, pages and images?

Thank you

Comment: some themes are support only for particular version of wordpress. So, I thing you are facing version issue. please mail me your info to moorthy0406@gmail.com

Comment: Turn on debug mode by modifying code in wp-config.php in your site root. Set define('WP_DEBUG','true') from define('WP_DEBUG','false') and see any error is visible.

Comment: @MonirulIslam I have turned debug to ('WP_DEBUG','true'), and refreshed / cleared the cache.. but the when I try to load "wp-config.php, the page also remains white?  [link](http://la-velle.co.za/wp-config.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete or rename the theme folder you uploaded and check. Your site will revert to a default theme after that and you can take on from there.

Also, make sure `WP_DEBUG` is set to true while in development so you can see what's going on.

Comment: thank you.  however the problem is that the theme I uploaded is not in my themes folder?

Comment: Rename the plugins directory momentarily to something like `_plugins`. It will deactivate all of them and show you the dashboard if the error is caused by a plugin instead.